# size of wire to run for aerobic septic system

Tags: wiring

Installing new septic system and from my breaker box to control panel is about 80-84ft. Installer said needed 20 amp breaker and was told by electrician could use 12/2 wire. The pump is 115v and 10 amps. The tank will be about 15-20ft from the control panel. Will the 12/2 wire work.

Answer (score 1):

12/2 is correct for 20A circuit. 20A circuit is likely correct for this pump - 15A would *probably* be OK (which could then use 14/2 wire), but 20A is better to handle pump startup.

Two key issues:

- This should probably be protected by GFCI. May or may not be required by code (depending on location), but a good idea when water is involved, at least if there is any plausible chance of human or animal contact. (Presumably if the tank is being serviced, the circuit would be turned off.)
- If you use cable then if any of the wire is outside then it must be outdoor/wet rated. If any of the cable is underground then it must be rated for direct burial.  Standard "12/2 Romex" is **not** wet rated.
- Alternatively, you can use wet-rated wire (which is pretty much any 12 AWG wire that is properly sold for use in conduit) in conduit. Conduit does not need to be buried as deep as cable.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd reconsider GFCI protection. Since the pump will be installed in the septic tank pump chamber and there will be nothing exposed to human contact, I see little need for GFCI protection. You certainly don't want nuisance trips that would allow sewage to backup.   Usually systems of this sort have 2 circuits, one for the pump and another for the control box. All this depends upon local codes, maybe the control box circuit should be GFCI protected, but I wouldn't GFCI protect the pump.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I am (fortunately!) not terribly familiar with sewage pumps. (Well, a *little* familiar, its a long (and irrelevant) story.) The issue is human contact, and definitely knowing if it has tripped GFCI or stopped working for any other reason is an issue (which relates to that long story...).

Comment: Also consider a local service shutoff that way you don't have to worry about putting locks on the breaker when you need to tinker with the motor.

Comment: @ratchetfreak  I believe that is required anyway. A local disconnect is almost always required.

Comment: I would expect the pump would be a definite purpose pump, and UL would specify GFCI protection if it was advisable. Otherwise GFCI protection requirements mostly applies to receptacles, and wouldn't apply.

Comment: I think ordinary users mostly see GFCI in reference to 15A/20A receptacles. But, for example, it applies to all equipment in/around a pool, whether hardwired or receptacle, and in a bathroom it applies to pretty much everything but lighting (and lighting too if it is above a tub/shower, unless specially designed for wet areas), and, for example, GFCI is now required (2014 NEC) for a dishwasher even if hardwired.